# How to Show Gif Animated Image for Image Preview Like MHFacebookImageViewer?

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, gif, animated

hi i have to show gif animated image preview like facebook in iOS. i was tried to use MHFacebookImageViewer for gif animated image. anybody can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage)
It is used in Flipborad.

Comment: do you know how to share on social media like whatsapp?